# events on nested movieclips inside a timeline placed instance are never dispatched

Tags: flash, actionscript-3

I am an AS3 code developer but this time I need to deal with a FLA that has an instance on timeline with complex nesting of movieclips and textfields (that are named via the instance field in Flash).
The problem is that events (I put in the Documentclass) on nested movieclips inside that timeline placed instance are never dispatched.

example code:

```
// my instance on Stage in all Frames of the timeline
public var thewall:MovieClip;

// event directly on thewall works 
// the event is dispatched correctly
thewall.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click);


// event on nested MovieClip userSharePost fails 
// the event is not dispatched
thewall.userSharePost.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK,click);


// event on nested TextField field1 fails as well
// the event is not dispatched
thewall.userSharePost.field1.addEventListener(TextEvent.LINK, linkCpechEvent);
```

How do I have to access them to get the Events dispatched?

Thank you very much in advance, Dennis

Answer (score 0):

Usually, you wouldn't be adding event-handlers to the nested movieclips in the main (stage) timeline. A movieclip is essentially a class, and all nested movieclips are properties of that class. So by the logic of OOP, all movieclips inside a movieclip should behave the same way when clicked. This means you would be adding event listeners to nested movieclips on the stage of the parent movieclip (if you get what I mean).

Comment: I know but the FLA was handed to me from a designer and has quite a complex arrangement of nested movieclips and textfields. what should I do? recreate the whole Design programmatically? that would take me probably 3 days. I would loose all advantages flash authoring tool offers. It sounds strange to me why a MovieClip created on stage cannot receive events I put in the document class.

Answer (score 0):

You can place one "onClick" event listener on the parent movieclip and have the handler check the event currentTarget. Problem with the way you need to listen to the events is, that once you assign an onClick listener to the "thewall" movieclip, it sort of "blocks" the events on it's children - even though you can still see the original source of the event in currentTarget.

Best practice in my experience is either to have one listener that checks the event source or, alternatively, instead of attaching an "onClick" on the instance of "thewall", have an additional transparent movieclip on the *bottom layer inside* the "thewall" and attach the click event to it - that way all movieclips above it will fire their own respective events, and click on the body of the container clip will fire on it's own.

Comment: thank you but in my case I have to detect a click on a html link inside a textfield. so how would I detect that the click came from the link and not from the textfield if it is both in the same display object (field1)?

Comment: I certainly is to good practice to track down click events by event.target. That works for banners and stuff that is on different Displayobjects. But for dynamic text and TextEvent.LINK Event I receive always the same target, the textfield display object!

Comment: A link inside a TextField can be given an "event:MYCUSTOMEVENT" format, so you can attach an event listener to the textfield that listens to it specifically and thus differentiate it from the regular clicks.